# Compare 2 db table values and update in 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am having 2 table in db, when i add any new value
I need to change the value of "Name" in table1.Name as Table2.Class,

```
table1
ID Name  item
1  A     Table
2  B     chair

table2
ID Class  Name
1  School  A
2  Office  B
```

Please help me to write mysql query for same.

```
What i tried:
 $query = "UPDATE table1 SET Name=table2.Class"
          . " WHERE table1.Name = table2.Name";
```

But not working.

Comment: why don't u use join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu have to join the tables table1 and table2 to get data from table2:

```
$query = "UPDATE table1 "
      . " INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name=table2.name"
      ." SET Name=table2.Class"
```